# OpenGL set a vertex element stride of zero

Tags: opengl

Problem X: I need to provide "compensation" streams for attributes that are not plugged by the mesh data, but the shader requires them.
(In d3d not matching the input layout is a hard error)

Solution Y: In D3D I've created a 16 bytes buffer initialized with some default color (when the missing semantic is color, let's take this as my typical use case) and specified a stride of zero so that one element is repeated whatever the index in the index buffer, and this way I don't need to clog VRAM with the biggest buffer that's necessary to cover all objects. This works in D3D.

But looking at [glVertexAttribPointer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml) I see that the API is eating away my stride and makes it automatic when I specify zero.

Any workaround ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disable the vertex attrib array and use `glVertexAttrib` to set the data that should be used.

Answer (score 5):

You can set a stride of zero with OpenGL 4.3's [separate attribute format](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Separate_attribute_format) API, or the ARB_vertex_attrib_binding extension:

```
glBindVertexBuffer(index, buffer, offset, 0);
```

The stride of zero will be a real stride of zero.

This also has the benefit of looking a lot more familiar to D3D users than the `glVertexAttribPointer` API.

Comment: hey that's very interesting. that's probably way easier since our engine is more based on d3d ways. I'll look into that tomorrow